# Use SSH keys for gradle authentication with Artifactory

Tags: gradle, artifactory, ssh-keys

Currently we are using hashed passwords with gradle for downloading and uploading artifacts from Artifactory.

Since Artifactory v.4.4 provides authentication using SSH keys we would like to use them for convenience purposes.

Is it possible to use SSH keys with gradle to download and upload (deploy) artifacts from/to Atrifactory?

Comment: This is a great feedback, we will look into supporting this capability with gradle client.
Currently if you are looking to use SSH authentication when uploading or downloading files you can use [JFrog CLI](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-cli-go).

The CLI was designed especially for these actions and utilises a lot of Artifactory's features such as checksum deploy, [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) to optimise searches to retrieve list of artifacts as well as concurrent upload and download to optimise those actions.

Comment: Adding this feature will be great